# Using tweepy to get the tweeter data?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, social-media

everyone. I am new to social media information mining. so I am so confusing when I running the  script below and get the result of "401" which I googled that I need authorization. Could anyone help me please, thank you very much.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = " XX"
access_token = "XX"
access_secret = "XX"

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)



def parse(cls, api, raw):
    status = cls.first_parse(api, raw)
    setattr(status, 'json', json.dumps(raw))
    return status


 tweepy.models.Status.first_parse = tweepy.models.Status.parse
 tweepy.models.Status.parse = parse


class MyListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('FILENAME.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
               return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True


twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#HASHTAG_TO_SEARCH'])
```

Comment: Did you get your keys and secrets correctly?

Comment: Yes. I have checked for several times. Here I just delete them for privacy concern...

Answer (score 0):

I runned your code with my own keys and secrets and it works like charm. You probably have to regenerate your consumer key and secret on Twitter's Application Management and try again.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thank you very much.